# Pantalla de carga con Angular

Tags: angular, carga, preloader

Quisiera saber como hacer una pantalla de carga con Angular.
Tengo echo el CSS y la pantalla de carga en si. Lo que necesito es que luego de la pantalla de carga, pasado cierto tiempo, me dispare el home.
Entiendo que esto requiere una función en mi componente principal pero no se bien como debería plantearlo para, una vez cargada la pantalla de carga, me dispare el home.

Alguna idea?!

Comment: es una web o una app movil? eso se puede, se conoce como SplashScreen y hay bastantes plugins para eso, me imagino que vienen adaptados para web y movil.

Comment: Es mi portafolio web.

Comment: Tal vez un poco de código ayude pero para darte un idea, en tu html de home agregas el componente de carga el cual debería aceptar de entrada un valor para mostrarse u ocultarse por ejemplo true y false. desde home debes mandar un true al iniciar el home para que se muestre y false para ocultarlo despues de cierto tiempo. Esta solución carga de inicio el home pero no se muestra el contenido de home hasta que tu ocultes tu componente de carga.